# Creating Records with restriction rules enforced

Tags: lightning, create-records, restrictionrules

I have a `RestrictionRule` set up on a custom object that compares a number field on said object to a custom number field on the current User (`$User`) record. The rule operates as expected for existing records - they can see exactly the records they should, but when the users for whom the rule applies attempt to create a record (with values that would grant them continued access to the record), they receive this error:

[image]

Are Users that have RestrictionRules applied to them just unable to create records? Any ideas on how to get around this would be appreciated. This was done on the standard lightning "new record" form.

Comment: Could you apply a validation rule in a step before this one? So you can only block the field display maybe...

Comment: @Cline what would a validation rule accomplish? even testing it with known-good values, and allowing the user to provide a known-good value, this message still appears.

Comment: Validation rules have specific methods for cases where the data is new (`ISNEW()`)  or just being changed (`ISCHANGED()`). You can specify whether a given profile can edit or create a record.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fields_useful_field_validation_formulas.htm&type=5

Comment: That works for editing, but I need to restrict viewing as well. Users that don't match the fields should not be able to read, edit, or delete said records.

Comment: For view records you can create a Profile and put the user there. So you can configure the view settings there.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have control over the Profile of my users, and am procedurally blocked from modifying settings through Profiles.